# Building a record with polymorphic assocation with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I would like to know why I am getting an error when I am building a record using FactoryGirl.

`Comment` model belongs to `user` and `commentable` through polymorphic association.

My factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :comment do
    text "Some text"
    user_id 1
    association :commentable, factory: :feedback
  end
end
```

When I'm build a `comment` record using FactoryGirl, I get:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
can't write unknown attribute `commentable_type'
```

I have no problem creating and manipulating `Comment` object in console. I can set and save `commentable_type` attribute freely. Also, `commentable_type` already exists in the `comments` table.

Any thoughts on why the error occurs?

Comment: Do you have `as: :commentable` in the relationship?

Comment: @Santosh I have `has_many :comments, as: :commentable`. In console, creating new `comment` object with association works without problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran all my migrations again using `rake db:reset` and now the error has disappeared. Before that,  I have tried to rollback the related migration and migrate again, but that did not make any change.

I still do not know what caused this error, but for now, it is fixed.

Comment: Same problem, same solution. That is strange. Thanks, you saved me some headache!